# sed delete characters between # and # and adding :'s in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I am working on a script dealing with the OUI mac address database (http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/oui/oui.txt) a sample output looks like this:

```
  40-25-C2   (hex)      Intel Corporate
  4025C2     (base 16)      Intel Corporate
                Lot 8, Jalan Hi-Tech 2/3
                Kulim Hi-Tech Park
                Kulim Kedah 09000
                MALAYSIA

  40-27-0B   (hex)      Mobileeco Co., Ltd
  40270B     (base 16)      Mobileeco Co., Ltd
                #2126, IT Tower B, Keumkang Penterium Bldg, 810
                Kwanyang-Dong, Dongan-Ku
                Anyang City Kyunggi-Do 431810
                KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
```

In the end I would like each line to look like this:

```
40:25:C2 Intel Corporate
40:27:0B Mobileeco Co., Ltd
```

I have no idea what the best way to go about this is, so far I have been taking it one step at a time this is what I have so far

```
sed '/base 16/!d' test.txt > test1.txt  # delete all extra lines
sed 's/^...//' test1.txt > test2.txt    # delete 3 spaces at the beginning of each line
```

The next step would be deleting the spaces and the (base 16) and I cant seem to get that to work... or how I would add the :'s

unless there is altogether a better way to do this.

also i will need to run this in both osx and ubuntu

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@devnull 's suggestion rewritten in POSIX sed:

```
sed -n '/base 16/{s/[[:blank:]]*\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)[[:blank:]]*([^)]*)[[:blank:]]*/\1:\2:\3 /p;}' file
```

The closing brace at the end needs to be prepended with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to say:

```
sed -r -n '/base 16/{s/\s+(..)(..)(..)\s+\([^)]*\)\s+/\1:\2:\3 /p}' test.txt
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
40:25:C2 Intel Corporate
40:27:0B Mobileeco Co., Ltd
```

---

Alternatively, you can say:

```
sed -n '/base 16/{s/\s*\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\s*([^)]*)\s*/\1:\2:\3 /p}' test.txt
```

This should work both on Ubuntu and OSX.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! any way i could change that so it would run on both osx and ubuntu? The script will need to be used on both and osx does not have -r

Comment: thanks for your help still having an issue  $ sed -n '/base 16/{s/\s*\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\s*([^)]*)\s*/\1:\2:\3 /p}' test.txt
sed: 1: "/base 16/{s/\s*\(..\)\( ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: @JJD It seems that BSD sed (on OSX) has even more limited support.  Try `grep "base 16" test.txt | sed 's/\s*\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\s*([^)]*)\s*/\1:\2:\3 /'`

Comment: If your Ubuntu `sed` doesn't recognize `\s` without `-r`, try to replace each `\s` with `[[:space:]]`. Maybe you will also need to replace any `x+` with `xx*` which is cumbersome but portable. In the end, the most portable solution may be the equivalent Perl script. (Hint: `s2p`.)

Comment: so close i am now getting  4025C2 :  :     Intel Corporate from the grep command

Comment: @devnull sadly no, so close i am now getting 4025C2 : : Intel Corporate from the grep command

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ sub("\n.*",""); gsub("-",":",$1); $2="" }1' RS= file
```

Results:

```
40:25:C2  Intel Corporate
40:27:0B  Mobileeco Co., Ltd
```

---

As nice as the solution above is, there remains an extra space in the output and it cheats by looking only at the first line of each record. After reading your code above, it looks like you are only interested in the second line of each record, i.e. the lines containing 'base 16'. Here's another solution using `awk` that deals with these issues. I have split it over many lines for readability:

```
awk '{
    n = split($2, a, OFS);

    gsub(/..\B/,"&:",a[1]);

    for (i=4;i<=n;i++) { 

        r = (r ? r OFS : "") a[i]; 
    }

    print a[1], r

}' FS="\n" RS= file
```

Results:

```
40:25:C2 Intel Corporate
40:27:0B Intel Corporate Mobileeco Co., Ltd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -F") +" '/hex/ {split($1,a," ");gsub(/-/,":",a[1]);print a[1],$2}' file
40:25:C2 Intel Corporate
40:27:0B Mobileeco Co., Ltd
```